# Execute certain amount of thread in a for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to build an application that executes a certain utility with multi threads. I want to control the amount of threads. Here is what I want to do:

```
    //initialize the number of threads to be 10
for(int i = 0; i < BIG_VALUE; i++) {
    RunnableObject rb = new RunnableObject(i);
    rb.run();
    //the for loop should run for 10 loops. When one of the threads finish its job
    //the for loop continues and runs another thread. The amount of threads should 
    //always be 10
}
```

How can I do so in Java?

Comment: are you looking for `ExecutorService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Java Executor framework http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Here an example of how to used

```
    public class SimpleThreadPool {



public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        Runnable worker = new WorkerThread('' + i);

        executor.execute(worker);

      }

    executor.shutdown();

    while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

    }

    System.out.println('Finished all threads');

}



 }






         public class WorkerThread implements Runnable {



private String command;

public WorkerThread(String s){

    this.command=s;

}



@Override
public void run() {

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+' Start. Command = '+command);

    processCommand();

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+' End.');

}



private void processCommand() {

    try {

        Thread.sleep(5000);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}



@Override
public String toString(){

    return this.command;

}

  }
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want. Moreover I wonder if there is an extra overhead, because when I set the pool size to 5 the procedure is much more slower compared with a single iteration.

Comment: Remember if you consider that the post response your issue mark as finish